# ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build : Build failed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker, apache

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  database:
    image: mysql
    container_name: database
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'

  php-apache:
    container_name: php-apache
    build:
      context: ./php
    ports:
        - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/laravel_doc
      - ./apache/default.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
    depends_on:
      - database
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev \
    mysql-client libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends \
    && pecl install imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick \
WORKDIR /var/www/laravel_doc

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

Comment: Please share the complete error message.